# How to set AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3 or equivalent?

Tags: r, oracle, rjava, rjdbc

In our organization we are running into the long standing Oracle "unsupported verifier type" bug, well documented since at least the early 2010s. I've been trying to determine how to set the bug fix of `AddVMOption -Doracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability=o3` in R using RJDBC or RJava, but can't seem to pinpoint how to do so. If anyone who's more familiar with these packages would have a solution, it would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Per request, here is a link describing this problem from 2012.
https://oraganism.wordpress.com/tag/unsupported-verifier-type/

Comment: "documented since at least the early 2010s." Please help us to help you and link to the research you have carried out so that we do not have to unnecessarily duplicate your efforts.